# is there a way to get utc nanoseconds for a date in uint64_t in c++

Tags: c++, boost, utc

I want to get number of nano seconds since epoch in uint64_t for a particular date, is there a function in any c++ library to get it.

Comment: boost datetime should have it. Not sure what date range can be represented with 64 bits in ns resolution

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the C++ 11 libraries, check out the [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library. You can use it to get the milliseconds since the Unix Epoch like this:

```
#include <chrono>

// ...

using namespace std::chrono;
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```

Comment: My question is regarding function which can take date as input argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) which extends `std::chrono` into the real of calendars:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    uint64_t k = (sys_days{2017_y/mar/21} + 10h + 27min + 5s + 
                  123456789ns).time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << k << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1490092025123456789
```

Comment: Note that Howard's library correctly includes the leap seconds since the start of the epoch.